# Binding custom directive to Observable in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, angular2-directives

I can't seem to figure out how data binding works with custom directives in Angular2.  Let's say I have a custom directive `FoobarDirective` that accepts an `@Input` that is an `Observable`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'foobar'
})
export class FoobarDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() anObservable: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.anObservable.subscribe(values => {
      console.log(values);
    });
  }
}
```

And an implementing component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
      <div foobar [anObservable]="toBind"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [FoobarDirective]
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  message: string;
  toBind: Subject<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.message = 'Angular2 works!';

     this.toBind = new Subject<string[]>();
     this.toBind.next(['a', 'b', 'c']);
  }
}
```

...but I get the following error:
`Can't bind to 'anObservable' since it isn't a known native property`.

Here's a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/1J6OKkglZEXC5rxeDYrQ/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is the selector of your directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[foobar]' // <------
})
export class FoobarDirective implements OnInit {
  (...)
}
```

Since you use the wrong selector, the directive isn't applied so Angular2 doesn't know about this input...